# word2vec in R - encoding issues when loading model

Tags: r, nlp, word2vec

After successfully training a model, which took about two days, with this code:

```
train_word2vec("/home/sveisa/may2022/test.txt", "/home/sveisa/may2022/test.bin", vectors=200, threads=4, window=12, cbow=TRUE, iter=5, force=TRUE, negative_samples=3)
```

I am unable to load it. It loads up to 51% and then I get this error message:

```
 in readChar(a, 1) : invalid UTF-8 input in readChar()
```

The file is about 2 GB.

I created a small version of the file, and everything worked.

The data contains non-English languages (although most is in Eng), could that be the problem? I have not found a way to load the model in a way that ignores encoding issues.

Comment: You could read and write your txt file with UTF-8 and then use `train_word2vec`. To read and write to get this encoding, use `txt = readLines(filename)`, `writeLines(txt, filename, useBytes = T)` <- that last argument is key!

Comment: library(xfun)
read_utf8("/home/sveisa/may2022/test.txt") to flag no UTF-8 lines so you can munge them.